# how can handle deeplink if it contain specific text, and launch app according the result

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking, android-deep-link, android-13

I'm trying to solve the problem of deeplink redirecting to the browser in android 13 instead of the application, but according to my research I haven't found a solution yet.

I have a deeplink like this: https://www.example.com/product-name-p-productid and I have this custom text "-p-" in all my product deeplinks.

Also for example this deeplink is redirecting to app: [www.example.com/account](http://www.example.com/account)

I wanna create logic if deeplink has this specific text, launch the app. I dont want to start the application in case of clicking on links that do not have this text. I tried to use pathAdvancedPattern but there is not well documentation about that, and I couldn't fix the problem with this way. Here is my manifest file intent-filter block:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*.example.com" />
                <data android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:path="/account" />
</intent-filter>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

I tried pathAdvancedPattern="/[-p-]" inside the data tag to launch app and a few different ways but I didn't get result.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="http" />
     <data android:scheme="https" />
     <data android:host="*.example.com" />
     <data android:host="example.com" />
     <data android:pathAdvancedPattern="\/[^\/]-p-..*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Pattern is `\/[^\/]-p-..*`:

- `\/` path must start with `/`
- After that, `[^\/]` any character except `/`
- Then match `-p-` exactly
- Then 1 or more characters (any): `..*`

PS: `pathAdvancedPattern` is supported on API >=31, for lower APIs you could use `pathPattern="\/..*-p-..*"`, because other symbols aren't supported AFAIK

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't launch the app

Comment: I have tested it and it works. Try removing `android:autoVerify="true"`, then test using this command: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#testing-filters

Comment: but im facing with this issue in android 13, autoVerify should be true. btw still it redirected to browser when i removed it

Comment: Try using single schema and single host

Comment: I tried but didn't get result